# Check for value in table variable in IIF

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to interrogate a result set for a particular value:

```
DECLARE @validIds;
SET @validIds = (SELECT id FROM client WHERE valid = 1);

IIF(@id IN @validIds, 1, 0)
```

This obviously isn't working, what's the best way to do this?

If I have the following "client" table:

```
id | valid
1  | 0
2  | 1
3  | 1
```

When @id is 1, I would expect the IIF to resolve to 0.

When @id is 2 or 3, I would expect the IIF to resolve to 1.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Apologies, I thought I specified SQL Server in the tags, but I missed it. Sample data and expectations have been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @validIds table (id int);
INSERT INTO @validIds VALUES (1),(2),(3)


DECLARE @Client table (id int);
INSERT INTO @Client VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
```

### Query

```
SELECT c.id  AS Client_ID
       ,CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @validIds WHERE id = c.id)
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Valid_ID]   
FROM @Client c
```

### Result

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╗
║ Client_ID ║ Valid_ID ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╣
║         1 ║        1 ║
║         2 ║        1 ║
║         3 ║        1 ║
║         4 ║        0 ║
║         5 ║        0 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a table variable to hold your valid ids. Then return 1 if your @id variable is in the list of valid ids - if not return 0.

```
DECLARE @validIds TABLE (id INT);

INSERT INTO @validIds (id) SELECT id FROM clients WHERE VALID = 1;

SELECT ISNULL((SELECT 1 from @validIds where @id = id), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

This would generate the output you want:

```
SELECT ID, CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS VALID FROM client
```